# Firebase-Initialization is not starting

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am a beginner in Android Studio and I faced a problem while I am trying to connect my app with firebase realtime database. I created a project in the firebase and use the firebase assist to make the connection, but the problem is the shows there is no Firebase-Initialization as shown below:

```
W/ComponentDiscovery: Application info not found.
    Could not retrieve metadata, returning empty list of registrars.
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId is not linked. Skipping initialization.
    com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

This is the project build

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

}
```

This is the app module build

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can you help me to fix this problem? I search and try many solutions but nothing work with me.

Comment: can you explain your problem with more detail? you send the warning, whats the error?

Comment: The problem in the connection with the firebase when I run my application, every things that related to the firebase "not linked and Skipping initialization." I tried to use the Manifest Merger but also didn't work. So what can I do to solve this issue and make the firebase connection done successfully without any problem?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to resolve firebase syncing issue is to login into the android studio with the same id as that of firebase and then go to Tools -> Firebase. Then sync with your project. It'll automatically download the google-services.json file which firebase use for authentication purpose.

Check this [Firebase Android Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for more info

Comment: I applied everything as written in all steps and still I have same problem